# In Macbook, what are Thunderbolt MAC addresses for, if ethernet adapters provide ones?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, thunderbolt, ethernet

I think [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69672/261713) and [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238217/261713) say that each ethernet adapter, such as [USB-C-Gigabit Ethernet Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJKF2ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter), has its own MAC address. So, that means Macbook (Pro) doesn't have a built-in ethernet card.

But I'm curious, what are the Thunderbolt MAC addresses then? In my MBP 13" (2015), `networksetup -listallhardwareports` command shows ethernet (MAC) addresses of `Thunderbolt 1` and `Thunderbolt 2`. Also, the result of `ifconfig -a` contains `bridge0` which has a MAC address.

What are they for, if every ethernet adapter decides the MAC address? Can I just ignore them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect two Thunderbolt-enabled Macs together using a Thunderbolt-to-Thunderbolt bridge connections, therefore you'd need each end to be able to identify itself.

More information here: https://9to5mac.com/2016/11/22/macbook-pro-thunderbolt-3-bridge-network-video/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a little surprised that Apple put such connecting feature while making it lack an ethernet card. Yeah, Thunderbolt might be more that that, but still.

Comment: Thunderbolt is actually Intel's invention, Apple was the first the mass adopt it.